# Find all instantiations of a class in a project

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans, ide

I have a class in a project, which is a huge codebase. I want to find all places in the code where this class is instantiated. (Actually, I want to know specifically where a certain member of this class is used).

Is there any IDE (eclipse, netbeans, intelliJ etc) which provides this functionality.

(Just searching with the class name gives over 250 matches even with "match case" and "match whole words" on)

Also, codebase is in PHP, so, searching for constructor won't work.

Comment: How do you instantiate your class? With `new Class();` ?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not (Its php !!) Also, maybe the class is used in composition with some other class as its member...I know a major portion of codebase, but of course, not all of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try PhpStorm (Similar to IntelliJ, but for PHP).

Go to class, place cursor on class name and press Alt+F7 - it will find all class usages in project, and categorize it. One of categories should be "New instance creation".